# SSIS - Load Point in Time tables - package flow?

Tags: ssis

First, I am newer to SSIS. I've been working with it for a while, but not very often and only for very basic simple things.

I have an SSIS package set up to load about 30 tables from a "live" data source. This has been working fine and we add new tables and update existing tables all the time. We use these tables to query for reports. This was not a planned out project, it was/is being done on the fly.

Then I was told I need to create "point in time" tables. Basically, duplicate tables from above need to be loaded 3 times every year: once in the beginning, middle and end of year. The data cannot change, but just like the "live" tables, it will be a work in progress with new fields/tables being added. I was under the gun to get it done now (along with a bunch of other stuff of course) and I did it in a way that "works for now", but cannot obviously stay this way. Here is basically what I did:

```
I created synonyms and revised all the stored procedures to use the synonyms

I set up an SSIS package with the following steps:

Execute SQL Task - Truncate tables

Execute SQL Task - Point synonyms to beginning of the year data source

Data Flow Task - Load tables

Execute SQL Task - Point synonyms to middle of the year data source

Data Flow Task - Load tables

Execute SQL Task - Point synonyms to end of the year data source

Data Flow Task - Load tables
```

Obviously it cannot stay this way as I now have 4 copies of the same Data Flow Tasks. What a nightmare if I need to add fields or a new table! At least I am able to use the same stored procedures though. Can someone please help me with an idea for a better set up?

Comment: Instead of synonyms, can you use views with UNION ALL statements that merge data from all four sources?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to do here.  Are you creating the point in time tables yourself, or are you using them as a source?

Comment: Views won't work... too much data, too many tables and too much processing time.

Comment: Creating the point in time tables myself.  I'm using the same stored procedures and data flow (which has 30 tables) as for the "live" tables.

Comment: Are there separate tables being loaded at each point in time, or do you have a single table being updated three times?

Comment: Sorry I'm just now getting back to you.  I was on vacation.  There are 30 tables being loaded each time (in one data flow), but they are the same 30 tables.  That's what I'm having an issue with.  I have copied the same data flow each time which means if I need to add/modify it, I have to make the changes 3 times.  I can't figure out how to design the package better.